# Locking down FreeNAS (FreeBSD) to just a single IP address

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, freebsd, truenas

I want to host a FreeNAS server (`Server B`) on the Internet for remote ZFS replication. `Server A`  is a FreeNAS server in an office with a dedicated IP behind a Firewall, which will be sending ZFS data to `Server B`.

I realize there are many ways to lock down `Server B` but I have to decided to keep it as simple as possible. My goal is to only allow traffic to `Server B` if it is coming from the IP Address of `Server A`.

I don't want to lockdown specific ports, I simply want to ignore/drop all traffic that doesn't originate from the IP Address of `Server A`.  Likewise, I want to allow all traffic originating from `Server A`'s IP address. Since I don't know what ports FreeNAS uses and might use in the future, I want to avoid picking and choosing points as to prevent a maintenance nightmare.

I probably know 3 or 4 Unix commands, so I'm far from an expert. Does anyone know the commands I need to run to lockdown my FreeNAS server to just a single IP?

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a root shell on `Server B`, you can use `ipfw` to only allow access from `Server A` (assuming IP 10.20.30.40 for Server A):

```
ipfw add allow all from me to me keep-state
ipfw add 40 allow ip from 10.20.30.40 to any
ipfw add 50 deny ip from any to any
```

This will only allow 10.20.30.40 to access it. Anything else will be denied. Just take care to not lock yourself out.

You could put that on a script, and add a `sleep 120 ; ipfw add 10 allow ip from any to any` on the last line of it, and run the script. If you somehow locks yourself out, ipfw will allow you back after 120 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Since any and all connections outside my IP address will be dropped, I assume this is as safe as it gets without using a VPN. I looked at the `ipfw` man pages but I couldn't figure out what the `40` and `50` numbers mean.

Comment: They are the priority. If you invert the numbers, `ipfw` will drop everything without going to the next rule.